# How can I install macOS on Aura Pro X2 SSD without having macOS 10.13 or higher on the host computer?

Tags: macos, mac, ssd, maverick

A few years ago I wiped the drive on my MacBook Air and reformatted it for Ubuntu. I’ve decided that I want to go back to macOS so I bought and installed a new [Aura Pro X2 SSD](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/aura-pro-x2).

I’ve now discovered that this SSD requires the host computer to have macOS 10.13 or higher prior to installation. Mine does not as it only has Ubuntu 18.04.

What can I do in order to get macOS back onto the machine?

Comment: Thanks for adding the make and model of the SSD. Definitely helps. Have you tried contacting Other World Computing (the manufacturers of the SSD) to see if they can assist? They really are some of the best macOS support people out there and I am sure if there is a solution, they can provide it to you.